# Можно ли как-то посмотреть, какие вводные данные для теста в codewars?

Tags: python

Решаю задачи на кодворс и когда мой код оказывается некорректным, получаю в качестве результата тестов, например:

"Example Tests
Test Case 1
(42, -9) should equal '42 -9'"

То есть сравнение, какой ответ у меня и каким ответ должен быть. Можно ли как-то посмотреть, какие вообще вводные данные для того теста, который у меня не проходит. Потому что я вижу, что есть ошибка, но не понимаю, какого именно теста она касается.

Comment: В данном случае первого. У вас неправильный формат результата.

Comment: Так у вас же указано в сообщении, что результат ожидается '42 -9'

Comment: @Эникейщик, там суть вопроса в другом - можно ли как-то посмотреть тесты. Есть другой пример: "(2, 1) should equal '3 1'". Здесь уже отличие не в формате, а в результате.

Comment: @SwaD, да, но там другой тип результата. Вопрос в том, как понять, результатом какого теста оно является

Comment: Залезть и пошуровать через dev tools не получится на большинстве платформ. Результаты приходят с backend. Вводные данные тоже скрыты, а вот подобрать ответы методом перебора можно.

Comment: @DiMithras Спасибо. Я так и понял, но ещё оставалась надежда, что я где-то что-то упустил и что можно их как-то глянуть.

Answer (score 3):

Напрямую на таких сайтах обычно тесты посмотреть нельзя. Но можно попытаться сделать небольшой реверс-инжиниринг: поскольку формат входных данных известен (описан в задании), то можно просто вывести их на экран. Например, если в тесте говорится, что входные данные - строка из двух целых чисел, то их можно узнать следующим образом:

```
a, b = input().split()
print(a, b)
```

Comment: Далеко не везде работает. В скрытых тестах обычно просто пишет уловие выполнено или нет, вывод в консоль скрыт.

Comment: @DiMithras понятно, что не везде. Но в данном случае тестовая система сообщает какой результат ожидается и какой получен.

Comment: @Эникейщик, прикольно, спасибо) Но я так понимаю, оно только один тест будет выводить. А там бывает, через штук 100 прогоняется, и написано только, что ожидалось столько-то, а у вас столько-то. Вот и думай потом, к какому тесту это относится)

Comment: не совсем понял. Вы получите входные данные, это и есть тест, к которому относится

Comment: @Эникейщик, условно говоря, у меня условиями задан список с числами. И в каждом тесте этот список разный. Когда какие-то из тестов не проходят, кодворс информирует меня о том, что ответ должен быть "10", к примеру, а у меня "9". Но не говорит, к какому именно тесту этот ответ относится, какой список содержал этот тест. Ваш способ мне помог увидеть самый первый тест (как я понимаю). А всего этих тестов может быть 60, 100, 200 и тд.  Но как я понял, узнать данные каждого теста нереально. Я пайтон учу относительно недавно, возможно, не совсем ясно сформулировал свой вопрос

Comment: А, верно. Там же после первой ошибки прерывается, значит только первые тест покажет. Тогда не подходит на codewars такой вариант

Answer (score 0):

посмотреть с какими данными сравнивается посмотреть нельзя (если тест правильно сделан), поскольку вы описываете лишь функцию, которая вызывается дальше и в функции зачастую ограничен доступ в некоторым библиотекам или функциям, чтоб получить какую-то более расширенную информацию

иногда помогает выводить на экран входные данные поскольку codewars выводит информацию о корректности или некорректности результата то вы хотя бы будете знать на каких входных данных ваш код выдает неправильный ответ

типа:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
    # дальше ваш код
```

тем не менее встречал задачи которые делались "в 1 строчку" с использованием некорректности при формировании задачи из серии

```
test = True
```

Comment: Да, получается, что только при помощи хитростей можно достучаться до данных теста, возможности их просмотреть не предусмотрено. Ну что ж, по крайней мере, я теперь знаю, что это не я такой слепой, что не смог сам найти)